# Count total and breakdown

Tags: mysql

I like to know how many users are from what city and Boroughs/Neighborhoods within that City. So I am looking for a query that will output the count results of these two. I have a table with user data, without the specific City and Boroughs/Neighborhoods, but with a postal code from each user. This can be used to match on the table postcodes, witch contains the City and Neighborhoods data.

Table **Users**

```
+----+--------------------+--------------+
| ID | User               | Postcode     |
+----+--------------------+--------------+
| 10 | John Doe           | 1100—99-AB   | 
| 11 | Shara Lee          | 1201—34-CD   |
| 12 | Patrick Star       | 1100—99-AB   |
| 13 | Oswald Harvey      | 1100—99-AB   |
| 14 | Samuel Jackson     | 1401—34-TR   |
| 15 | Richard Lionheart  | 1744—39-AA   |
| 16 | Shamanta Jones     | 2334—95-AC   |
| 17 | James Rooney       | 1401—34-TR   |
| 18 | Chandler Bing      | 3334—23-AA   |
| 19 | Jessica Burner     | 2277—99-RA   |
+----+--------------------+--------------+
```

Table **Postcodes**

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+
| Postcode   | City         | Borough     |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1100—99-AB | New York     | Manhattan   |
| 1201—34-CD | New York     | Manhattan   |
| 1401—34-TR | New York     | Bronx       |
| 1744—39-AA | New York     | Harlem      |
| 2334—95-AC | Newark       |             |
| 6334—95-AC | Detroit      | Greektown   |
| 3334—23-AA | Philadelphia | Penn Center |
| 2277—99-RA | Newark       |             |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Result I am after

```
+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| City         | Total_City   | Borough     | Total_Borough |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| New York     | 7            | Manhattan   | 4             |
| New York     | 7            | Bronx       | 2             |
| New York     | 7            | Harlem      | 1             |
| Newark       | 2            |             | 2             |
| Philadelphia | 1            | Penn Center | 1             |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

This is how far I got with my query. This does correctly count the number Boroughs/Neighborhoods, but unfortunately it does not show the total city count.

```
SELECT City, Borough, COUNT(City) AS Total_City, COUNT(Borough) AS Total_Borough, 
    FROM `users` u 
    LEFT JOIN `postcodes` p ON p.postcode = u.postcode
GROUP BY City, Borough
```

See my example on http://rextester.com/DFRV4183

Comment: Nearly, but see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry, you are quite right. I've added a working example from Rextester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way...

```
SELECT a.*, b.total total_city
  FROM 
     ( SELECT p.city
            , p.borough
            , COUNT(*) total 
         FROM postcodes p 
         JOIN myusers u 
           ON u.postcode = p.postcode 
        GROUP 
           BY city
            , borough
     ) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT p.city
            , COUNT(*) total
         FROM postcodes p
         JOIN myusers u 
       ON u.postcode = p.postcode 
    GROUP 
           BY city
     ) b
    ON b.city = a.city;
```

You can also do something like this, but I'm not convinced that the result is easier to understand...

```
SELECT city 
     , borough
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM postcodes p 
  JOIN myusers u 
    ON u.postcode = p.postcode 
 GROUP 
    BY city
     , borough WITH ROLLUP;
```

Finally, you can use variables. Maybe I'll post an answer along those lines later... if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.City, Borough, Total_City, Total_Borough from
  (SELECT City, coalesce(COUNT(User),0) AS Total_City
    FROM `Users` u 
    right JOIN `Postcodes` p ON p.postcode = u.postcode
  GROUP BY City ) as c
inner join 
(
SELECT City, coalesce(Borough,'Undefined')as Borough,coalesce( COUNT(User),0) AS Total_Borough, p.postcode
    FROM `users` u 
    right JOIN `postcodes` p ON p.postcode = u.postcode
GROUP BY City, Borough
) as b 
on b.City=c.City
```

Comment: What does the outer query do?

Comment: Thnx, I suppose using subquerys is the way to go. Your suggestion seems close, but unfortunately it does not list all the Boroughs. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e7c6e/12

Comment: try it now and tell me.